# Capybara Screenshot formatted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

My Capybara-screenshots are looking silly - it does not apply any stylesheets.

and, it seems to make screenshots not exactly after error occurs: by producing a error manually i see different views as opened by the gem.

what do i have to configure?

here is my `spec/rails_helper.rb`
rails-6.1
and rails s -p 3000 is running alongside the tests

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
#Capybara.server = :puma
Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000/"
Capybara::Screenshot.after_save_html do |path|
  `open #{path}`
end
Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = :keep_last_run

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.9'
end
```

on the output-file, the first line ist

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--><head><base href='http://localhost:3000/' />
```

so, it seems that capybara-screenshot has checked the [css](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#better-looking-html-screenshots)https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#better-looking-html-screenshots

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you're looking at the HTML "screenshots" instead of the jpg screenshots?  The HTML ones will never be fully correct, and really should only be used for verifying HTML structure, not for current values/state. The reason for this is it saves the HTML and attributes, but can't save the JS properties of each element, so it won't save the current state of checkboxes, etc.  The jpg screenshots, on the other hand, are a picture of what the browser actually rendered. As for why the HTML versions wouldn't be loading the CSS, take a look at the source of the file and make sure a `<base>` element is correctly being injected into the `<head>` element of the page.

Comment: now i was able to produce screenshots in png, with some steps: ```page.save_screenshot('screenshot.png'), save_and_open_page, Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_open_image```. But, all of them are looking as silly as the previous html - error-pages

Comment: @chmich Sounds like your assets aren't being built

Comment: Yes, thomas, but is there a special configuration necessary for it?

Comment: @chmich No - if you're using the standard Rails configuration the assets should be built as needed -- if you've modified the standard Rails asset configuration then you may need to build them manually - it should be fully visible in the browser while your tests are running if they weren't being built though.